# Putting both source code and executable file in CD/DVD

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to burn my program in CD?DVD booth as an executable file, together with source code. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already have a working CD/DVD with executable (autostart working etc.), you can simply put the source code on GitHub/GitLab or else and add a link to the manual. You are publishing the source code anyway, then you can already do it the "standard" way.

Of course this only works if all your users have access to the internet.